A continuous map always sends a connected set to a connected set. Why is the continuity important?
A nonempty set $S$ in a topological space with a topology $\cal T$ is connected if it is not the union of two nonempty disjoint open subsets, i.e., if it is not possible to write $ S=A \cup B$ where $ A,  B\in {\cal{T}}$ and $ A, B\neq \emptyset$ and $ A\cap B = \emptyset$.
To show that a continuous map is always sending a connected set to a connected set, consider a map linking two sets: $f:~D\longrightarrow S$. Suppose the set $S$ is not connected, so $ S=A \cup B$
where $ A,  B\in {\cal{T}}$ and $ A, B\neq \emptyset$ and $ A\cap B = \emptyset$.
We now have to show that the preimages $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are disjoint. If there is a point $y\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$, then $f(y)\in A\cap B$ which was assumed to be $\emptyset$. Hence a contradiction.
Now, where exactly should the continuity of $f$ be used? The continuity warrants that both $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are open. Why does this matter?
PS.
I see that a Moderator has associated my question with that one. Sadly, that answer concentrates solely on the necessity for the map to be surjective. It fails to explain why it needs to be also continuous -- which is the principal point of my question here.

see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481942/continuous-image-of-a-connected-set?rq=1

Notice that the definition is incomplete. The empty space is not connected.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you. Fixed.

Notice that every set with more than 1 element can be written as the disjoint union of two nonempty sets. The key for connectedness is that they are open. Without continuity, there is no reason to expect the pre image of $A$ and $B$ to be open.

@Malady Got your point. Thank you. Would you consider to present is as an Answer?
